# Mechanize 405 error while authenticating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

I'm trying to authenticate with a website using the Mechanize gem and am receiving the following error:

```
405 => Net::HTTPMethodNotAllowed for https://www.mygreatlakes.org/educate/login/snapAuthentication -- unhandled response
```

The form uses `POST` as the method, so I'm not sure why this error is occurring. Using [Hurl It](https://www.hurl.it/), I was able to see that this URL accepts GET requests. Visiting this URL returns a 401 error stating

```
Error 401: Authentication Failed: Authentication method not supported: GET
```

Perhaps this is worth noting as well: there is a username input and another input outside of the form, and I'm wondering if their placement outside of the form means JavaScript is being used to append these to the request?

Here's the code I'm using to login:

```
  def scraper
    agent = Mechanize.new { |a| a.log = Logger.new("log/mechanize.log") }
    agent.request_headers = {'User-agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11'}

    login_page = agent.get('https://www.mygreatlakes.org/educate/login.html')
    login_form = login_page.form_with(id: 'snapLogin')
    username_field = login_form.field_with(name: "userName")
    username_field.value = "username"
    login_page = login_form.submit

    pin_form = login_page.form_with(id: 'securityPinModel')
    pin_field = pin_form.field_with(name: "pinNumber")
    pin_field.value = "pin"
    pin_page = pin_form.submit

    password_form = pin_page.form_with(id: "frm")
    password_field = password_form.field_with(name: "password")
    password_field.value = "password"
    password_page = password_form.submit

    @output = password_page.body
  end
```

Here's the HTML from the form on the password page that's throwing the error:

```
<form id="frm" class="slow-load log-in" autocomplete="OFF" action="snapAuthentication" method="post">
                    <div id="errors" class="message alert hide-this authErrors" role="alert" style="display: none;">
                        <strong>Please Correct These Errors</strong><br>
                        <ul id="errorList" style="outline: none;" tabindex="-1">

                        </ul>
                    </div>      


<div>
    <p>Here's the identity image and catchphrase you selected:</p>
    <p class="display-img">
        <img style="height: 65px; width: 65px;" alt="Pirate Flag" src="image.img?id=7"> 
        <br>
        <strong class="blue">catchphrase</strong>
    </p>
</div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="password">Password</label> 
                            <input id="password" name="password" class="short input-field" type="password" value="" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="orange" id="authenticate">Continue</button>
                    <p class="help"><a class="nowrap" href="/educate/login/trouble.html">I forgot my password</a></p>
                </form>
<input id="userName" name="userName" type="hidden" value="username">
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="value">
```

And here's my log file:

```
I, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.626822 #48752]  INFO -- : form encoding: utf-8
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.626999 #48752] DEBUG -- : query: "password=password"
I, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.629630 #48752]  INFO -- : Net::HTTP::Post: /educate/login/snapAuthentication
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.629804 #48752] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-encoding => gzip,deflate,identity
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.629886 #48752] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept => */*
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.629956 #48752] DEBUG -- : request-header: user-agent => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.630022 #48752] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-charset => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.630087 #48752] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-language => en-us,en;q=0.5
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.630168 #48752] DEBUG -- : request-header: cookie => GLDCID=.mad; JSESSIONID_007_infoserv=0001LgdwpswRf5r66r4pAgOtaOM:153b6ufq4; TLTSID=0.5241251b52c6a
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.630235 #48752] DEBUG -- : request-header: host => www.mygreatlakes.org
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.630310 #48752] DEBUG -- : request-header: referer => https://www.mygreatlakes.org/educate/login/imageAndPassword.html
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.630377 #48752] DEBUG -- : request-header: content-type => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.630441 #48752] DEBUG -- : request-header: content-length => 17
I, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.680558 #48752]  INFO -- : status: Net::HTTPMethodNotAllowed 1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.680816 #48752] DEBUG -- : response-header: date => Mon, 09 Nov 2015 02:26:22 GMT
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.680936 #48752] DEBUG -- : response-header: server => Apache
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.681050 #48752] DEBUG -- : response-header: strict-transport-security => max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.681164 #48752] DEBUG -- : response-header: x-xss-protection => 1; mode=block
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.681274 #48752] DEBUG -- : response-header: x-frame-options => DENY
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.681384 #48752] DEBUG -- : response-header: x-content-type-options => nosniff
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.681493 #48752] DEBUG -- : response-header: allow => GET,HEAD
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.681601 #48752] DEBUG -- : response-header: content-length => 0
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.681710 #48752] DEBUG -- : response-header: content-type => text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.681818 #48752] DEBUG -- : response-header: content-language => en-US
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.681926 #48752] DEBUG -- : response-header: keep-alive => timeout=4, max=95
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.682098 #48752] DEBUG -- : response-header: connection => Keep-Alive
D, [2015-11-08T21:26:22.682332 #48752] DEBUG -- : Read 0 bytes (0 total)
```

Comment: I'm assuming that's not the real username and password. I don't think you can expect any help with this unless you post that.

Answer (score -1):

The error means the site is blocking the method you're trying to connect to it.

Basically the admins of the site are blocking the specific method you're trying to use OR the site is on 'read only', you can however remove this block and here's a link to teach you how to do it:

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html

As for the 401 error it can indicate old cached data, a missing cookie, or a security conflict. 401 errors may also indicate a server error.

Comment: This much I understand - so why would a form with a method `POST` have an action which rejects this method? Submitting this form via the browser with my credentials works just fine, so something isn't being passed correctly.

Comment: Exactly, the method you're trying to pass is being rejected from the site. Just because your credentials work doesn't mean you can pass `POST` methods, `GRAB` methods or anything. The method has to be _allowed_ on the site in order for it to be passed from the program. It might even have something to do with the host of the site, they're very big on disallowing certain methods for their own security.

Comment: I understand that having credentials doesn't give me free rein to use any method of my choosing, but the form that exists on the site uses a POST method for the action which rejects the POST method. I'm hoping to gain some insight as to why this is the case, and what alternatives there are for me to authenticate.